# Centered Bullet in Multi-line Itemize

Tags: itemize

First post here.

I am trying to vertically center bullet point's for an item of text that spans multiple lines. I have been able to get the desired result using minipage but would like to see if that is the correct way.

Here is a MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item{\blindtext}
        \item\begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}{\blindtext}\end{minipage}     %This produces the desired outcome

    \end{itemize}
    \end{document}
```

If this is indeed the best method, would someone please explain how I would redefine the item command to include the minipage?

Comment: Hint: the line width inside a list is no longer `\textwidth` (which is the full width of the text block), try `\linewidth` instead (it dynamically adapts)

Comment: You probably need to better explain what you mean by `but would like to see if that is the correct way`

Comment: Thanks ! I would like to know if there is a better way to get the result. I would also like to know the correct syntax to redefine \item to include the minipage definition -- Something along the lines of 

 \renewcommand{\item}[1]{\item\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}{%1}\end{minipage} ??

Comment: Update your question with a better explanation. I would not do it in the first place, it looks strange and makes the text harder to read harder to follow when a new item starts

Comment: My application is on a resume, where there will only be 3 lines but on second thought i think you might be right!

Comment: Why not just use moderncv instead of doing things by hand